# In how many ways can the letters of the word ASSASSINATION be arranged so that no two vowels are together?

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, permutations

$$\fbox{X}A\fbox{X}A\fbox{X}A\fbox{X}I\fbox{X}I\fbox{X}O\fbox{X}$$

Now, there are $\frac{6!}{3!2!}$ ways to arrange the vowels as I have placed them in the above schematic. Also, consonants will be fixed iin the places marked $X$. Again, there are $\frac{7!}{4!2!}$ ways to arrange the consonants. So, there are

$$\frac{6!}{3!2!}\cdot\frac{7!}{4!2!}$$

ways to arrange the letters of the word ASSASSINATION so that no two vowels are together. Am I correct?

Comment: Why can't our word begin or end (or both) with a consonant?

Comment: @lulu My mistake. Edited.

Comment: "Again" in what sense is this task similar to the preceding task?  (You don't justify it at all.)

Comment: I don't understand your argument. It would seem to me that you need to first do a Stars and Bars count to get the number of patterns (be careful:  you need to solve $x_1+\cdots + x_7=7$ where $x_i≥1$ for $i\in \{2, \cdots, 6\} $ but $x_1, x_7$ might be $0$.).

Comment: For the pattern $CVCVCVCVCVCVC$, you are correct. However, the pattern may begin or end with a vowel, hence you may have one or two groups of two consonants together, or one group of three consonants.

Comment: As pointed out, your attempt is incorrect. Will you try and correct it ?

Comment: The problem does not say that no two consonants are adjacent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can arrange the consonants $SSSSNTN$ in $\frac{7!}{4!2!}$ ways.

Independently of this, you can insert the vowels $AAIAIO$ in the eight slots before, between and after each vowel. However that means two slots are unfilled - let’s denote these as $XX$.

Now you can arrange the slot-fillers $AAIAIOXX$ in $\frac{8!}{3!2!2!}$ ways.

Multiply these together and you have your total number of arrangements where no two vowels are together.

Answer (score 2):

I expected you to try to correct your attempt; but as a solution has been posted, I will show another method which can be applied to any consonant-vowel permutation problem with a non-adjacent clause.

- Consider the $7$ consonants as blue balls, the $6$ vowels as red balls, and place the consonants one by one followed by placing vowels one by one.
- Each consonant placed creates an extra placement possibility for the next ball, but each vowel placed "eats up" one place for the next one due to the non-adjacent clause, thus $$\dfrac{(1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5\cdot6\cdot7)(8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3)}{4!2!3!2!} =176,400$$

the denominator, of course, correcting for multiple letters of a kind

Answer (score 1):

Since no one has (yet) highjacked the analysis in lulu's comment:

Normally, I would consider Inclusion-Exclusion for this type of problem.  Here however, the Stars and Bars approach is simply much easier.

Any satisfying string of characters will be formatted like:

```
_V_V_V_V_V_V_
```

where the V's represent the 6 vowels.

Let $~A~$ denote the number of ways that the $~6~$ vowels can be permuted.

Let $~B~$ denote the number of ways that the $~7~$ consonants can be permuted.

Let $~C~$ denote the number of different ways of satisfactorily *spacing* the vowels.

Then, the desired computation is

$$A \times B \times C.$$

---

**Note**
Suppose that $~n_1, ~n_2, ~n_3, ~$ are each positive integers, and that you have a [Multi-Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) that contains:

- An element $~r~$ with multiplicity $~n_1.~$
- An element $~s~$ with multiplicity $~n_2.~$
- $~n_3~$ other elements, each with a multiplicity of $~1.$

Then, the number of ways of permuting the elements in this multiset is

$$\frac{(n_1 + n_2 + n_3)!}{(n_1!) \times (n_2!)}.$$

Therefore,

$$A = \frac{6!}{3! \times 2!}, ~B = 
\frac{7!}{4! \times 2!}.$$

So, the entire problem has been reduced to enumerating $C.$

---

Consider the enumeration of the number of satisfying solutions to the following problem.

- $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_7 = 7.$
- $x_1, x_7 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$
- $x_2, x_3, \cdots, x_6 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 1}}.$

The above constraints perfectly capture the requirement that none of the $~6~$ vowels are next to each other.  That is, $~x_1~$ and $~x_7~$ are each allowed to equal $~0,~$ which corresponds to the fact that both the first character and the last character of the sequence of characters are permitted to be a vowel.

Then, the requirement that each of $~x_2, \cdots, x_6~$ be $~\geq 1~$ captures the fact that none of the vowels may be *next to each other*.

For Stars and Bars theory, see
[this article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) and
[this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Per Stars and Bars theory, the number of solutions to:

- $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_k = n ~: ~n \in \Bbb{Z^+}$
- $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_k \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}$

is $~\displaystyle \binom{n + [k-1]}{k-1}.$

So, the Stars and Bars problem that is being used to compute the value $C$ must be converted into the above format, where each of the variables has the constraint that $~x_i \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

In the Stars and Bars computation of C, the variables $~x_1,~$ and $~x_7~$ are already okay.

To adjust the other variables, $~x_2, \cdots, x_6,~$ use the following change of variable:

For $~i \in \{2,3,\cdots,6\},~$ let $~y_i = x_i - 1.$

Therefore, for $~i \in \{2,3,\cdots,6\},~$, you will have that :

- $y_i \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}} \iff x_i \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 
  1}}.$
- $x_1 + x_7 + (y_2 + \cdots + y_6) = 7 - 5 = 2 \iff $ 
  $x_1 + x_7 + (x_2 + \cdots + x_6) = 7.$

Therefore, the use of Stars and Bars theory to
computate C has been converted to enumerating the number of solutions to

- $x_1 + x_7 + (y_2 + \cdots + y_6) = 2$
- $x_1, x_7 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$
- $y_2, \cdots, y_6 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

Therefore, per Stars and Bars theory, 
 $C = \displaystyle \binom{2 + 6}{6} = \binom{8}{6} = 28.$

---

$\underline{\text{Final Computation}}$

$$A \times B \times C = 
\frac{6!}{3! \times 2!}, \times \frac{7!}{4! \times 2!}
 \times 28 = 176400.$$